# $a+OA\lt b+OB\lt c+OC$ when $a\lt b\lt c$ in a triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

In the triangle $\triangle ABC$ of sides $a,b,c$ let $O$ be the incenter. If $a\lt b\lt c$ then (it is easy to prove that) $OC\lt OB\lt OA$.
Prove  that
$$\max \{a+OA, b+OB, c+OC\}=c+OC$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$c+\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)^2+r^2}>b+\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+c-b}{2}\right)^2+r^2}$$ and$$c+\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)^2+r^2}>a+\sqrt{\left(\frac{b+c-a}{2}\right)^2+r^2}.$$ 
We'll prove a first inequality. The second inequality can be proved by the same way.

We need to prove that
$$c-b>\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{(a+c-b)^2+4r^2}-\sqrt{(a+b-c)^2+4r^2}\right)$$ or
$$2(c-b)>\frac{(a+c-b)^2-(a+b-c)^2}{\sqrt{(a+c-b)^2+4r^2}+\sqrt{(a+b-c)^2+4r^2}}$$ or
$$\sqrt{(a+c-b)^2+4r^2}+\sqrt{(a+b-c)^2+4r^2}>2a,$$ which is true because
$$\sqrt{(a+c-b)^2+4r^2}+\sqrt{(a+b-c)^2+4r^2}>a+c-b+a+b-c=2a.$$

Comment: +1, essentially, this is equivalent to saying that $\sqrt{x^2+h} -x$ is decreasing.

Comment: A pleasure, Michael. What seems nice to me in this problem is that the largest side added with the smallest segment is always greater  than the analogous sums. Thanks for the best title.